# Installing Java for Eclipse on OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I've been trying to install Java, mainly for Eclipse, in the latest *OSX (10.11)* but it just wont work. I installed *JRE 8 and 7* and when I launch Eclipse it says that the `Java version isn't suitable for it` (Says I have `1.6.0_65`) and that I need `version 1.7 or higher`. Then I tried to install the *JDK 7 and 8*. Both installers get stuck on

```
Verifying JDK 7/8 Update xx.pkg
```

and wont move on. I don't know what else to do. Can anyone help me?

Thank you, 
Vasco

Comment: When you have JDK, you don't need JRE.

Comment: Delete Eclipse and uninstall Java. Install the JDK version you want. Download Eclipse. Start Eclipse. Profit. Personally, anytime I want to install another java version I only use the jre, but for starting out I ALWAYS download the JDK.

Comment: Deleting both and reinstalling did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem trying to open the `JDK 8 Update 211.pkg`. I uninstalled the Java JRE using the comand line instructions [here](https://java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml). I then restarted my machine, and tried opening the `JDK 8 Update 211.pkg` again and it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which JVM Eclipse should use via [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). That might get you going using the Java 7 or 8 JRE's that you installed, but if you're going to use Eclipse for any Java-based development you'll really want the JDK instead. So you should pursue why the JDK installations are failing on your machine (probably another SO question).

Answer (score 0):

You should use this link to apple to download the correct java for your mac: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US